# Java Regex match everything up to and after

Tags: java, regex

I have strings of the form:
something~#~something.

Essentially I am using ~#~ as a delimiter, but I would like to only split the first element from the rest of the elements.

For instance, if I had the following string:
What~#~AGreat~#~Day

I would like my first match to be "What"
and my second match to be "AGreat~#~Day.

The actual strings I'm working with look like this:
A1~#~@NP->_A1
So they're not limited to alphanumeric characters. Can anyone help? I tried looking around for a similar problem but I can't seem to get it working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String first = input.substring(0, input.indexOf("~#~"));
String second = input.substring(input.indexOf("~#~") + 3, input.length());
```

Output:

```
first:  What
second: AGreat~#~Day
```

Comment: works like a charm, I was about to correct the +3, but I see you've beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `split(String regex, int limit)` method. For example this code

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abc.bcd.cde";
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\\.", 2)));
    }
}
```

produces the following output:

```
[abc, bcd.cde]
```